# Data Migration from AWS RDS to Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, migration, etl, data-migration

I have my application's database running in AWS RDS (postgresql). I need to migrate the data from AWS to Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

This is a kind of ETL process and I need to do some calculations/computations/aggregations on the Data from Postgresql and put it in a different schema in Azure SQL Data Warehouse for reporting purpose.
Also, I need to sync the data on a regular basis without duplication.

I am new to this Data Migration concept and kindly let me know  what are the best possible ways to achieve this task?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Azure datafactory is the option for you. It is a cloud data integration service, to compose data storage, movement, and processing services into automated data pipelines.

Please find the Postgresql connector below.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-onprem-postgresql-connector](http://a%20cloud%20data%20integration%20service,%20to%20compose%20data%20storage,%20movement,%20and%20processing%20services%20into%20automated%20data%20pipelines.)

On the transform part you may have to put in some custom intermediate steps to do the data massaging.

Comment: This connector is for On-Premise right? Will it support connecting to AWS DB in my case?

Comment: yes this is . But I believe it should work as long as you provide the connection details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Azure datafactory suggestion? 
Did it solve your issue?

If not, you can try using Alooma. This solution can replicate PostgreSQL database hosted on Amazon RDS to Azure SQL data warehouse in near real time. (https://www.alooma.com/integrations/postgresql/)

**Follow this steps to migrate from RDS to Azure SQL:**

Verify your host configuration

1. On the RDS dashboard under Parameter Groups, navigate to the group that's associated with your instance.
2. Verify that hot_standby and hot_standby_feedback are set to 1.
3. Verify that max_standby_archive_delay and max_standby_streaming_delay are greater than 0 (we recommend 30000).
4. If any of the parameter values need to be changed, click Edit Parameters.

**Connect to Alooma**

1. You can connect via SSH server (https://support.alooma.com/hc/en-us/articles/214021869-Connecting-to-an-input-via-SSH) or to to whitelist access to Alooma's IP addresses.

52.35.19.31/32

52.88.52.130/32

52.26.47.1/32

52.24.172.83/32

2. Add and name your PostreSQL input from the Plumbing screen and enter the following details:
   Hostname or IP address of the PostgreSQL server (default port is 5432)
   User name and Password
   Database name
3. Choose the replication method you'd like to use for PostgreSQL database replication
   For full dump/load replication, provide:

A space- or comma-separated list of the names of the tables you want to replicate.
The frequency at which you'd like to replicate your tables. The more frequent, the more fresh your data will be, but the more load it puts on your PostgreSQL database.

**For incremental dump/load replication, provide:**

A table/update indicator column pairs for each table you want to replicate. 
Don't have an update indicator column? Let us know! We can still make incremental load work for you.

Keep the mapping mode to the default of OneClick if you'd like Alooma to automatically map all PostgreSQL tables exactly to your target data warehouse. Otherwise, they'll have to be mapped manually from the Mapper screen.